# How to offset a track map based on one set of coordinates

Tags: excel

I have a set of coordinates X and Y for a line around a race track. I want to offset this line to give me an inner and outer set of track coordinates but i am not sure how to best do this. I want it to look like the track below. Thanks

[image]

Comment: What are you using to actually draw the line?

Comment: So i used excel to plot the track but i can also plot it in matlab. I dont have the mapping toolbox in matlab so i cant use those features. I did import the matlab plot into illustrator and did an offset which is what the picture is but its not right and i still cannot seem to export the actual x,y coordinates back into excel from illustrator. So i am wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Don't do an offset in illustrator, instead, increase the stroke weight, then use `Object -> Path -> Outline Stroke` this will give you three lines (best seen in artwork mode), pick the two you want and delete the third. You can use `PathPoint` and `anchor`  objects to export the anchor point coordinates.

Comment: Thank you. Increasing the stroke weight worked better in terms of the shape but i still cannot export the coordinates. i know i can hover over each point and see the coordinates that way but there is over 3000 coordinates and so i dont want to have to do that for everyone. I thought i could export just the coordinates in a txt file or something.

Comment: This [can be scripted in Illustrator](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4388468#4388468). Alternatively, you can export it as an SVG

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.05/anthony1.html)

```
 For any point P with coordinates (x,y) you want to transform P by

x is transformed to s(x - c) + c
y is transformed to t(y - d) + d
```

where, the center has coordinates (c,d), s is the scaling factor in the x direction and t is the scaling factor in the y direction

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to find the slope at each point; you can use point slope formula using two surrounding points. Using that slope, you can find the perpendicular slope at each point; just the negative reciprocal of the original slope. Then you can use this equation to solve for the change in x: Δx = sqrt(1/(m^2 +1))

And then solve for Δy using point slope formula. Then Δx and Δy can be added and subtracted to the original points.
I got this equation by using the point slope formula: Δy = m(Δx) and substitute Δy into c= (Δx)^2 + (Δy)^2 to get c = (Δx)^2 + (mΔx)^2.  "c" here is an arbitrary value of the amount you want to expand the track. and this can be rearranged to give us Δx = sqrt(c/(m^2 +1)).

Answer (score 0):

Found a script for you [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/100957/script-to-get-x-y-positions-from-a-path-in-a-vector-image)

The only problem with it is you will need to ungroup and release compound paths on your drawing before running it. Also you will need to select all the paths for this script to run on them properly as it work on the current selection.